# Having trouble savings links to a list variable with selenium

Tags: python

Practicing web scraping through selenium by opening user's dating profiles through a dating site. I need selenium to save a href link for every profile on the page but unfortunately it only saves the first profile on the list, rather than creating a list variable with all the links saved. All of the profiles start with the same two div class/style which is "member-thumbnail" and "position: absolute". Thank you for any help that you can offer.

Here is the website code:

```
<div class="member-thumbnail">
    <div style="position: absolute;">
        <a href="/Member/Details/LvL-Up">
        <img src="//storage.com/imgcdn/m/t/502b24cb-3f75-49a1-a61a-ae80e18d86a0" class="presenceLine online">
        </a>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
link_list = []
link_list = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.member-thumbnail a').get_attribute('href')
length_link_list = len(link_list)
for i in range (0, length_link_list):
    browser.get(link_list[i])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `find_elements_by_css_selector` instead of `find_element_by_css_selector`
[link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

if you're going to loop through the whole list returned from `find_elements_by_css_selector`, consider using this instead, a bit more pythonic way.

```
link_list = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.member-thumbnail a')
for element in linklist:
    browser.get(element.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: Getting this error, wasn't getting this error previously:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\artur\Desktop\feabie.py", line 26, in <module>
    link_list = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.member-thumbnail a').get_attribute('href')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'

Comment: find_elements_by_css_selector return a list of web elements, you should use get_attribute('href') inside the loop for each element @ArturPodlesniy

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer to include the full code? That way I can upvote the full answer. Thank you.

Comment: My code that generated that error message was this:

Comment: link_list = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.member-thumbnail a').get_attribute('href')

Comment: You don't need to upvote it if you don't want to. You should try to figure things out by yourself, that's better than copying code from others. You should learn to debug from stack trace as well. That error you just sent me is easy to debugged if you try to @ArturPodlesniy

Comment: Hint: link_list[i].get_attribute('href') @ArturPodlesniy

Comment: I learn from seeing and adjusting code that already works to see what breaks it and what makes it work, thanks for your condescension though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202690/discussion-between-hung-nguyn-and-artur-podlesniy).